# Prevent Android from downloading video from website

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am a web developer delivering video on a webpage. When I link to a video file (.m4v), Android wants to download the video to the phone, and then you can play the video from your phone.

On an iPhone (and Palm Pre), however, the same link just opens up the video in the media player, and returns to the web page upon completion.

My website is for members only, and I would prefer them not to be able to download the videos. Obviously I know there is no way to completely protect the videos, but I would like to at least make it appear like you can't download the video for a casual user. Streaming is not really an option.

So my question is how do I deliver the iPhone experience (opening in a media player) on an Android phone?

FYI, I've been testing this out with my Evo.

Answer (score 0):

If Youtube is an option for you, the default Youtube app will do what you want (open the video on its own Activity, then returning back to the browser). Obviously, you might know that there are thousands of Youtube downloader, so it's not a really secure way to prevent downloads.

Hint: Youtube has "private sharing"

Another alternative, if your users uses Android 2.2 (Froyo) or the SkyFire browser is Flash. Froyo and SkyFire allows running Flash in the browser.